# What is the bit width of a single webassembly instruction?

Tags: serialization, webassembly, bytecode, instruction-set

I know that webassembly currently supports a 32 bit architecture, so I am supposing that, like RISCV32, that its base instruction set has instructions which are 32 bit wide (Of course, RISCV32 supports 16-bit compressed instructions and 48-bit ones as well). RISC-V's instructions are interpreted mostly as left-endian (in terms of bit indices).

For example, in RISC-V, we can have an instruction like `lui` (load upper-immediate to register), that embeds a 20-bit immediate into an instruction, has a 5-bit field to encode the desitination register, and a 7-bit format to specify the opcode. Among other things, the opcode contains two bits at the beginning that connote whether the instruction is compressed or not. This is encoded in the specification, where `lui` has an `LUI` opcode.:

[image: RISC-V opcode listing]

RISC-V instructions have a variety of different layouts specified in the specification as well, and for example, the `lui` instruction takes the "U" format, so we know exactly where the 20-bit field is and where the 5-bit destination register is in the serialization:
[image: RISC-V instruction layouts]

What is the bit width of a wasm instruction? What are the possible layouts of a wasm instruction? Are there compressed instruction formats for webassembly, such as 16-bit instructions for very common operations?

If webassembly instructions are variable-width, how is the width of an instruction encoded for the interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

Binary WASM bytecode has variable-length instruction, not fixed-width like a RISC CPU.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly#Code_representation has an example.

It's not intended to be executed directly, but rather JITed into native machine code, thus a fixed-width format that would require multiple instructions for some 32 or 64-bit constants would make more work for the JIT optimizer.  And would be less compact in the WASM binary format, and more instructions to parse.

Much better for the JIT optimizer to know the ultimate goal is to materialize a whole constant, since some ISAs will be able to do that in one instruction, and others will need it split up in different parts depending on the ISA.  e.g. 20:12 for RISC-V, 16:16 for ARM `movw`/`movk` or MIPS, or if the constant only has set bits in a narrow region, ARM rotated immediates can maybe still use one instruction.  Or AArch64 bit-pattern immediates can materialize a constant like `0x01010101` (or `0x0101010101010101`) in a single 32-bit instruction.

TL:DR: Don't make the JIT put the pieces back together before breaking back down into asm that works for the target machine.

And in general, variable-length isn't much of a problem for a stream that will be parsed once by software anyway, not decoded repeatedly by hardware every time through a loop.

Answer (score 1):

### Examples

A lot of webassembly instructions take up one byte. For example, the [left shift instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Reference/Numeric/Left_shift) are `i32.shl` and`i64.shl` and take single byte opcodes `0x74` and `0x86` without any subsequent values, while the `i32.const` instruction for example starts with `0x41` and takes from 2 to 6 bytes.

| Instruction | Opcode |
| --- | --- |
| `i32.const` | `0x41` |
| `i64.const` | `0x42` |
| `f32.const` | `0x43` |
| `f64.const` | `0x44` |
| - | - |
| `i32.shl` | `0x74` |
| `i64.shl` | `0x86` |
| - | - |
| `i32.eqz` | `0x45` |
| `i32.eq` | `0x46` |
| `i64.eqz` | `0x50` |
| `i64.eq` | `0x51` |

And so on. The values here are taken from the MDN website. See the [Numeric Instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Reference/Numeric).

### Encoding Numbers

Some instructions such as the `const` above require specifying the immediate, which increases the overall size of the instruction. The immediates are encoded in [LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128), and the variant depends on whether the integer is signed or unsigned. Those are normally given in the specification.

LEB128 is roughly this: bits are padded to a multiple of seven, split into groups and the last bit is used to determine whether the end is reached. Those numbers are [constrained to their maximum width](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/values.html#integers). Floating point numbers are [encoded in IEE-754](https://float.exposed/b0x8f06)

> The `const` instructions are followed by the respective literal.
> [image]
> All other numeric instructions are plain opcodes without any immediates.
> [image]

> Source: https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/instructions.html#numeric-instructions

Comment: Those are opcodes, not whole instructions.  Seeing `0x41` means the next 4 bytes are a 32-bit constant (to be pushed on the stack).  Or however they encode the operands; perhaps something more compact for small i64 values?  But anyway, `i64.const 10` is not a 1-byte *instruction*.  It starts with a 1-byte *opcode*.  (x86 machine code is like that, with many opcodes being 1 byte.)

Comment: Yup I have noticed that. To be fair, it is only clear which instructions take immediates on going through the specification, and the MDN page doesn't tell you about that structure.

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe most of them are leb128 encoded so that it doesn't depend on their width. I also think that there may be restrictions on the size of the leb128 numbers depending on whether it is an `i64` or `i32`.

Answer (score 1):

Wasm instructions are represented with a unique opcode (typically 1 byte, more for newer instruction), followed by the encodings of immediate operands, for instructions that have them. There is no specific length, it depends on both the opcode and the immediate values.

For example:

- `i32.add` is opcode 0x6A with no immediates;
- `i64.const i` is opcode 0x42, followed by a variable-length encoding of `i` in LEB128 format;
- `br_table l* ld` is opcode 0x0E, followed by a variable-length encoding of the length of `l*` in LEB128, followed by as many variable-length encodings of the label indices in `l*`, followed by the variable-length encoding of label index `ld`.

See the [binary grammar](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/instructions.html) in the specification for details. A Wasm decoder is essentially "parsing" the binary input according to this grammar.

Comment: And it's a stack machine, so instructions don't need to encode operands other than immediates, that's just implicit from the stack, I assume.  That's pretty standard for bytecode that's going to be JIT-compiled, makes it compact.  Unlike a hardware ISA where you'd have an add-immediate instruction instead of having to decode 2 separate instructions to load an immediate and then use it as an operand for an add.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some citations from the current specification v2.0 related to the [instructions](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/instructions.html) (as "seen" by the specification itself):

> some instructions also have static immediate arguments, typically
> indices or type annotations, which are part of the instruction itself.

> Some instructions are structured in that they bracket nested sequences of instructions.

In relation to the [nesting](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/appendix/implementation.html?highlight=implementation%20limitations):

> Implementations typically impose additional restrictions on a number of aspects of a WebAssembly module or execution

Then, one of the noted implementation limitations is:

> the nesting depth of structured control instructions

As the nesting depth of the instructions is not strictly defined by the specification, but its left to the implementation to choose, that means that there is **no** limit of the instructions length regardless are they encoded as binary or text, as per the specification.

Even if we ignore the structured instructions (as we should not), there are many instructions having vectors as arguments. The vectors length is limited to 2^32-1. If my memory serves me right, there was and an instruction having vector of vectors as an argument.